# Object Mapper class use to store data in Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, objectmapper

Let start from background of my problem.

I have a `Person` class which is used to parse `JSON` response

```
class Person: NSObject, Mappable {

        var ID : String?
        var firstName : String?
        var lastName : String?

        convenience required init?(map: Map) {
                self.init()

            }

            func mapping(map: Map) {
                patientsCount <- map["patientsCount"]
                status <- map["status"]
                message <- map["Message"]
                patientSearchArray <- map["patientsList_JSON"]
            }
    }
```

While on the other I have another class names `PersonMO` which is used to save record in `CoreData`

```
        @objc(Event)
        class PersonMO: NSManagedObject {

        @NSManaged var ID : String?
        @NSManaged var firstName : String?
        @NSManaged var lastName : String?

    }
```

Now comes to main point. The problem I am facing is that I have to create two different classes for one purpose. Just like When `JSON` comes form `Server Side` then I have to parse it into `Person` class and then I want to save that `Person` into `Core Data` for that I have to convert `Person` class object to `PersonMO` class object. Which seems like a bad practice. 
Is there any way to use just one Class `Person` will be used to parse `JSON` and at the same time I want to use that `Person` class to store data in Core Data.

Comment: It doesn't look like ObjectMappper supports this. But ObjectMappper is open source, so you could modify it and send a pull request to incorporate your change.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this if so please share as I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

A single `Person` class like this should be enough, would serve both cases.

```
class Person: NSManagedObject, Mappable { 

@NSManaged var ID : String?
@NSManaged var firstName : String?
@NSManaged var lastName : String?

convenience required init?(map: Map) {
    self.init()

}

func mapping(map: Map) {
    patientsCount <- map["patientsCount"]
    status <- map["status"]
    message <- map["Message"]
    patientSearchArray <- map["patientsList_JSON"]
}
}
```

`NSManagedObject` is subclass of `NSObject` so it can be used just like your Person class with Mappable. `@NSManaged` is a indication that its managed by CoreData, still it can be used like normal variables.

Comment: I have already tried this approach. When you set NSManagedObject as a Parent class you have to implement  NSManagedObject's init methods then init?(map: Map) method does not call. So also mapping(map: Map) will also not called.

Comment: What library are you using for Mapping? wanted to know how init?(map: Map) is getting called

Comment: I am using ObjectMappper to parse JSON response.